# Replace missing values with corresponding day mean

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, mean, missing-data

My dataset: MyData

```
     Day Sales
12-01-17    NA
12-01-17    NA
13-01-17    13
14-01-17    2
12-01-17    33
13-01-17    NA
13-01-17    NA
13-01-17    NA
14-01-17    11
12-01-17    23
13-01-17    21
14-01-17    NA
```

I would like to replace missing sales for a day with mean sales for that day. So `NA` on `12-01-2017` has the value average of 33, 23 i.e 28.

The R code I tried is this. Here MyData_NA is having only rows with Sales = NA and MyData_Daymean has mean sales grouped by day.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(MyData_NA)){if (MyData_NA[i,day] == MyData_Daymean[i,1])
{ MyData_NA[i,2] <- MyData_Daymean[i,2] }}
```

This does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`. We can use `mutate` with `ifelse` to replace the missing values with `NA`. The key is to use `group_by` on the same `Day` so the mean calculation would be that group only.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  mutate(Sales = ifelse(is.na(Sales), mean(Sales, na.rm = TRUE), Sales)) %>%
  ungroup()
dt2
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#        Day Sales
#     <fctr> <dbl>
# 1 12-01-17  28.0
# 2 13-01-17  13.0
# 3 14-01-17   2.0
# 4 12-01-17  33.0
# 5 13-01-17  17.0
# 6 14-01-17  11.0
# 7 12-01-17  23.0
# 8 13-01-17  21.0
# 9 14-01-17   6.5
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "     Day Sales
12-01-17    NA
                 13-01-17    13
                 14-01-17    2
                 12-01-17    33
                 13-01-17    NA
                 14-01-17    11
                 12-01-17    23
                 13-01-17    21
                 14-01-17    NA",
                 header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Looks like the solution!. Thanks much...

Comment: Hi @www , I am getting this error on running a similar code: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incompatible types, expecting a numeric vector.`  Can you please also help with this?

Comment: What is the type of your `Sales` column? Make sure they are numeric.

Comment: My Sales column is of type INT

Comment: And it should be fine. Not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
dt$Sales <-  with(dt, ave(Sales, Day, FUN = na.aggregate))
dt$Sales
#[1] 28.0 13.0  2.0 33.0 17.0 11.0 23.0 21.0  6.5
```

Or with `data.table` assuming the 'Sales' is `numeric` type

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, Sales := na.aggregate(Sales), Day]
```